# how to use different config files on build?

Tags: go, build

I have a config file for my go program, and clearly it has different values when I run locally vs on my server.

My boss recently asked me to switch deployment methods so that I run "go build" locally, and then deploy that build. Thus, I need to switch out my global config file each time I build.

Unfortunately, I have a piss poor memory, and I'll almost certainly forget to switch these files out. I would love if there were way (maybe in a build script file, or anything) to use different config file when building as opposed to running "go run main.go" as I usually do when I am working locally on development.

Does anyone have any ideas or best practices here?

Note: I already gitignore this file, but since building if basically solidifies the whole program (including these set variables) into a single file, just having another file on the server wouldn't do.

Thanks all!

Comment: Is this config file a go file you include in the binary? If so, put your config in a separate file, and read it when you run the program,

Comment: I have a util package, with a file global_config_live.go that defines and exports all the variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints).

Here's an example:

**config.go**

```
//go:build !live

// Add your local config here
```

**config_live.go**

```
//go:build live

// Add your server config here
```

Use `go build` to build the local version.  Use `go build -tags live` to build the server version.